# API fails after moving to new server

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I use Passport for my api and everything was working perfectly. I moved to a new server where I also have a staging server setup. I have everything exactly identical, but my production API is responding with unauthorized. When I switch to my staging api, the API works perfectly fine. Even while on the same database.

I am able to login, I just can't access any routes inside `auth:api`. The `oauth-private` and `oauth-public` are the same as well.

```
Route::post('oauth/token', 'AccessTokenController@issueToken');  // works

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('/user/{id}', 'UserController@index'); // Fails
});`
```

Comment: Did you generate your encryption keys? `php artisan passport:keys`

Comment: I did, still same issue. I even used old ones as well. I assume the keys work correctly, since I can log in.

Comment: How are you logging in users? user/password?

Comment: E-mail/password via oauth/token.